# How can I improve performance on a MongoDB aggregation query?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using the following query to get the count of records per day where the air temperature is bellow 7.2 degree. The documentation recommends to use the aggregation framework since it is faster than the map reduce

```
db.maxial.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        time:1,
        temp:1,
        frio: {
            $cond: [
                { $lte: [ "$temp", 7.2 ] },
                0.25,
                0
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        time: {
            $gte: new Date('11/01/2011'),
            $lt: new Date('11/03/2011')
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            ord_date: {
                day: { $dayOfMonth: "$time" },
                month: { $month: "$time" },
                year: { $year: "$time" }
            }
        },
        horasFrio: { $sum: '$frio' }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        '_id.ord_date': 1
    }
}])
```

I get an average execution time of 2 secs. Am I doing something wrong? I am already using indexes on `time` and `temp` field.

Comment: I doubt that MongoDB is using your indexes here. Try switching `$match` and `$project` blocks to ensure that `time` index is used.

Comment: If you want MongoDB to efficiently use `temp` index, add `temp: { $lte: 7.2 }` check to `$match` block. Besides, why do you want to `$sum` zero values?

Comment: That's a good question. The problem is that I need to get a `0` when a day doesn't have any documents that match the condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have indexes defined but you are not using them. In order for an aggregation pipeline to "use" an index the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage must be implemented first. Also if you omit the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) entirely and just include this in [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) you are doing it in the most efficient way.

```js
db.maxial.aggregate( [
    { "$match": {
        "time": {
            "$gte": new Date('2011-11-01'),
            "$lt": new Date('2011-11-03')
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
           "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$time" },
           "month": { "$month": "$time" },
           "year": { "$year": "$time" }
       },
       "horasFrio": {
          "$sum": { 
              "$cond": [{ "$lte": [ "$temp", 7.2 ] }, 0.25, 0 ]
          }
       }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1} }
])
```

Project does not provide the benefits people think it does in terms of "reducing fields" in a direct way.

And beware JavaScript "Date" object constructors. Unless you issue in the right way you will get a locally converted date rather then the UTC time reference you should be issuing. That and other misconceptions are cleared up in the re-written listing.

Comment: I am using a `date` type field on the database. Do I have another (and more efficient) way to do the `$match`?

Comment: @Hugo Date is the most efficient storage for this type, I am just telling you to beware how you instantiate. Not all forms produce a UTC time. The comment was made that you could also compound index on "temp". It is better practice to "post fill" zero values than to try and "brute force" the zero's into your response. The benefits from query filtering on the index usually outweigh the cost of post processing.

Comment: By the way, the `$sort`is working only at day of month. It is not working at date. Could you help me on that?

Comment: @Hugo You can always ask another question. But the hint here is do not sort on "_id" but on the individual properties of that sub-document.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the performance of an aggregate query you would have to use the various pipeline stages and in the right order.
You can use the **$match** at first and later follow by **$limit** and **$skip** if needed. These all will shorten the number of records to be traversed for grouping and hence improves the performance.